# Making my div elements not overflowing in angular

Tags: html, css

I have a issue about my div elements. When i add a lot cards then my div elements are overflowing

[image: there is a picture:]

and here is my app.component.html

```
<app-nav></app-nav>
<div class="div" >
<div class="category" >
<app-category></app-category>
 </div>
<div class="product">
  <app-products></app-products>
 </div>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and here is my app.css.html

```
.div{
display: flex;
height: 100%;
position: relative;

}
.category{
height: 100%;
}
.product{
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need absolute positioning here? This is most likely the reason why this is happening.

Comment: Maybe could be your "position: absolute" that is messing up with layout. Try removing it

Comment: I'd like to see what you want to achieve first! Because, indeed, solving the overflow is easy, but I believe you want to achieve something specific without the cards overflowing!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the position **absolute** of *product*..

Comment: Welcome! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and improve your answer.